# CSS - split screen on pc but stacked on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to split my page to 4 equal parts, and the top left I want to divide horizontally to 2 parts.
My main concern is how it will be on mobile, I don't want it to be split like on pc, I want it to be stacked (block on top on another). as explained in pic.
I thought about bootstrap grid but I couldn't make it.
What I have so far is something along the lines of:

```
<style>
html, body { height:100%; margin:0; padding:0 }
div { position:fixed; width:50%; height:50% }
#NW { top:0;   left:0;   background:orange  }
#NE { top:0;   left:50%; background:blue    }
#SW { top:50%; left:0;   background:green   }
#SE { top:50%; left:50%; background:red     }    ​
</style>
<div id="NW"></div>
<div id="NE"></div>
<div id="SE"></div>​
<div id="SW"></div>
```

I want the divs to occupy 100% of screen height and width. (with bootstrap I had problems doing this)

[image: The way I want it to look]

Comment: Have you looked at the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)?

Comment: yes, that was how I initially addressed this issue, but for some reason things got messy. boxes weren't fully width so there was lots of white space, and things that probably shouldn't happen. that is why i ask here. thanks

Comment: You need to clarify your question; nowhere does it state that you are trying to occupy the entire screen.

Comment: you're right, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I'm not familiar with Bootstrap, so this may not be as simple as the examples that use it. This is a plain CSS example.

---

You can do this with CSS [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Notes:

- I changed the `id`s to `class`es for better maintainability. (it seems you only have short ones and tall ones of the same width). If you are styling each one individually (like you are doing with colors), then leave the `id`s.
- I put the two shorter ones in a container `<div>` so that they would stay together, even with a float.
- As @shirfy mentioned below, always put the desktop style in the media query to improve mobile loading speeds. This is known as mobile-first web design.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aormbf96/).

And here's a code snippet (try resizing the page: under 480px width it will be considered "mobile" and resize, and vice versa):

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.container > div {
    width: 100%;
}
div.short {
    height: 100px; 
}
div.tall {
    height: 200px;
}
/* media query CSS */
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    /* Notice how this is the desktop style */
    div {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
/* These styles are for coloring - ignore them */
div.container > div:nth-of-type(1) { background-color: #ffdddd; }
div.container > div:nth-of-type(2) { background-color: #ffddff; }
body > div:nth-of-type(2) { background-color: #ffffdd; }
body > div:nth-of-type(3) { background-color: #ddffdd; }
body > div:nth-of-type(4) { background-color: #ddddff; }
```

```html
<!-- Note this container class -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="short">div1</div>
  <div class="short">div2</div>
</div>
<div class="tall">div3</div>
<div class="tall">div4</div>
<div class="tall">div5</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest the mobile first approach, `div { width: 50%; }` by default and use `min-width: 480px` in the media-query with 50% width for the div in there. Better performance for handheld devices.

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous comment and can't edit it, I meant that 100% width should be added in the media-query, but I guess you figured that out. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks alot! few issues tho:
1. when adding the bootstrap css (I use it on the page for other elements), It ruins the display of what you're trying to do. when I remove the bootstrap css it works fine. any way to workaround this?
2. I also changed div heights from 100/200px to 25% and 50% because I want full screen split and it works fine. when I resize screen it also works, but when I use my galaxy S5 it looks like the PC css and not the mobile's... weird, no?
Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: With Bootstrap, I'll try to see if I can find any conflicting styles in the documentation. Regarding the Galaxy S5, that might be because the screen width is over 480px. You might want to change it to a fixed width (not based on pixels) with a unit such as `in` on `em` instead of `px`.

Comment: You're right! Fixed the galaxy issue. still stuck with the bootstrap css conflict. tried using custom divs and use <div class="custom short"> or <div class="custom><div class="short"> and still no go... thanks!

Comment: Found it! the problem was with <div class="container"> because bootstrap has its own use for it. I changed some things, made it work PERFECTLY! Thanks alot!!

Comment: new problem occurs tho: when adding <!DOCTYPE html> there's problems with the height of the page. I tried adding height:100% to body and html, but still no go :'(

Comment: @user3720583 I'm glad you figured it out! As for your last problem, my only suggestion is to make sure you add a specific height to *every* div, even the container.

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrap grids for this:
Include bootstrap.css in you page and include this meta tag
 `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
 and the grid code will be as
`<div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
             <div class="col-sm-12"> 
             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-12"> 
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-12">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
         </div>
     </div>
</div>`

Comment: Thanks, but this does cause issues with different heights for different divs (different data length), and it ruins the display.

Comment: this issue can be eliminated by giving same height to different div and using appropriate padding in div with smaller data-length. If it create too much white space you can change the layout accordingly. The idea is too avoiding grid in mobile while maintaining it in the desktop screen.